# Index out of bounds after splitting the line and retrieving index 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file with following way

1 "Captain America"

2 "Spider-Man"

3 "The Hulk"

i get a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

```
    val file = sc.textFile(".../marvel-names.txt").collect
    val lines=file.map(x=>(x.split('\"')(1)))
    lines.foreach(println)
```

i am pretty sure the superhero names are at index 1 because i tried printing the index positions also.
Am new to scala-spark

Comment: Think !!! when you split by last `"`.

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine:

```
scala> val file = spark.read.textFile("/home/anurag/SH.txt").collect
file: Array[String] = Array(1 "Captain America", 2 "Spider-Man", 3 "The Hulk")

scala>  val lines = file.map(x=>(x.split('\"')(1)))
lines: Array[String] = Array(Captain America, Spider-Man, The Hulk)

scala> lines.foreach(println)
Captain America
Spider-Man
The Hulk
```

Comment: Yeah just came to know...the file is quite large with 20000 such names, the data might be corrupted...yeah the file wasnt in proper format, i put a if condition with length>=2 and it worked...thanks

Comment: Yes it could be that there are no data present in file.